# How to test median category of ordinal variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

I have an ordinal variable with 6 categories. The first category that goes above 50% of cumulative frequency is called the median category. How should I test whether this category is truly a median category? Should I state the hypothesis as in this case, the cumulative frequency of the sixth category is at least 50% and alternative hypothesis such as the cumulative frequency of the fourth category is less than 50 %? Should I then proceed with testing proportion with a binomial test?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not say how the entries in your table arose. I explore two scenarios.

**Assuming categories 1 through 6 are bins into which 44 values have been sorted:** You have $12$ observations below the 5th bin and $16$ above. If there is a 50-50 chance of falling above or below that bin, then the probability that $12$ or fewer out of $12 + 16 = 28$ fall below is $0.2858.$

```
pbinom(12, 28, .5)
[1] 0.2857941
```

This is the P-value of a
test of the null hypothesis that observations not in the 5th bin are equally likely to fall above or below it. We cannot reject that null hypothesis at the 5% level.

**Assuming that labels 1 through 6 are levels of a true categorical variable:**  The $n=44$ ordinal observations `x` are

```
x = rep(1:6, c(2,2,3,5,16,16))
x
 [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
[23] 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6

median(x)
[1] 5
```

The median of the categorical variable ***is*** $5,$ and
there is no hypothesis to be tested.

Comment: The values are from a questionnaire survey, where each response category is the time period like once a day, once a week...